# Continue (save state) in nested recursive method

Tags: python, loops, recursion, nested-loops

I'm working on a web crawler. The crawler is built for web page which has many categories. These categories can have subcategories, the same for subcategories etc.

So it can seems like this:

[image]

So I made a recursive method which provides deep first search.

```
def deep_search(url):

    if is_leaf(url):
       return get_data(url)

    for url in get_subcategories(url):
        deep_search(url)
```

This method works fine but it takes a long time to finish so there are situations when connection falls or another error raises.

What would you do to remember state in case that error occures and next time it continues from this state?

I can't just remember last 'url' or category since there are loops and the program would not know what 'urls' and categories has been stored in upper loops.

Comment: are you sure that even works? You seem to be throwing away the data when it gets returned if the url is a leaf url, in the line - `for url in get_subcategories(url):
        deep_search(url)` .

Comment: Just want to make sure, that you are aware of [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/)

Comment: Take a look at Scrapy, if you haven't.

Comment: @AnandSKumar It's just pseudocode, in fact it's way more difficult. But yes, it works. The question is how to remember the state. But thanks for comment.

Comment: Generally you want to make a pool of urls to crawl and create set of workers (threads) which take urls from the pool to process (extract data and add new urls to the pool if there are any on a page)

Comment: Guys, why do you recommend Scrapy? What is the advantage (I know that it probably can process javascript etc.)?

Comment: make it non-recursive using generators? `yield get_data(url)`...

Comment: @hiroprotagonist How it helps? What if the program falls? How it would know from where to start?

Comment: you cach the exception before you yield; the next time you call the generator it will contiune where it left off last time.

Comment: https://brett.is/writing/about/my-python-web-crawler/ - take a look at this article. If you want it the code to continue after hangs then you should save queue somewhere else or use some 3rd party software

Comment: @hiroprotagonist Yes but it works only when the program is running. Let's say that there is a situation when the electricity was shut down for 6 hours ( :) ). There should be something written into the file to know where to continue from.

Comment: if you want it to continue after a power failure then you need to make the state of the function persistent in some way (database of some kind). no way around that. but that would be a different question i guess...

Answer (score 1):

If the order of search paths is stable (every time your script visits sub-categories in the same order), then you can maintain a branch number list in your DFS, and make it persistent - save it in a file or database:

```
current_path = [] # save the path currently visited

def deep_search(url, last_saved_path=None):
   if is_leaf(url):
       if last_saved_path:
           # Continue where you left off
           if path_reached(last_saved_path):
               data = get_data(url)
       else:    # first run
           data = get_data(url)        
       # save the whole path persistently
       save_to_file(current_path)
       # add data to result
   else:
       for index, url in enumerate(get_subcategories(url)):
           current_path.append(index)
           deep_search(url, last_saved_path)
           del current_path[-1]

def path_reached(old_path):
    print old_path, current_path
    # if the path has been visited in last run
    for i,index in enumerate(current_path):
        if index < old_path[i]:
            return False
        elif index > old_path[i]:
            return True
    return True
```

When running the crawler for a second time, you can load the saved path and start where you left off:

```
# first run 
deep_search(url)
# subsequent runs
last_path = load_last_saved_path_from_file()
deep_search(url, last_path)
```

That said, I think in a web crawler there are 2 kind of tasks: traversing the graph and downloading data. And it's better to keep them separate: use the above DFS algorithm (plus logic to skip paths that have been visited) to traverse the links, and save the download urls in a queue; Then start a bunch of workers to take urls from the queue and download. This way, you just need to record the current position in queue if interrupted.

And I recommend `scrapy` to you, I haven't read scrapy source, but I guess it implements all of the above, and more.

Answer (score 0):

As a simple hint you can use a `try-except` statement to handle your Errors and save the relative `url` and as a good choice for such task you can use `collections.deque` with 1 capacity,and check it in next iterations.

Demo :

from collections import deque

```
def deep_search(url,deq=deque(maxlen=1)):

    if is_leaf(url):
       return get_data(url)
  try:
    for url in get_subcategories(url):
      if deq[0]==url:
        deep_search(url,deq)

  except : #you can put the error title after except 
    deq.append(url)
```

But as a more pythonic way for dealing with networks you can use [networkx](http://networkx.github.io/).

> NetworkX is a Python language software package for the creation, manipulation, and study of the structure, dynamics, and functions of complex networks.